# Set image into imageview from camera folder

Tags: android

i have an `ImageView` in which Gallery selected images need to set but when i select camera folder images, selected image is not set in `ImageView` .

```
 if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY ) {

            Uri selectedImg = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImg, filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);
            mUserProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(selectedImg!=null) { c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImg, filePath, null, null, null); }else{ Toast.makeText(mContext,"This image does not exiest in device",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return; } f = new File(picturePath);
```

mUserProfileImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options));
// Call this after copied image , and delete then after

```
    if (f != null) {
        f.delete();  // previously i set f in imageView and already handled NPE, so no crash appeared.
    }
```

I got the solution of problem, when i capture images from camera , it got stored in temp.png, and i copy this image to some other path and delete that temp.png, So when i again try to set the deleted image , it does not set and i handled the NEP also.

I debugged and corrected the code . :)

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question, but post a complete solution that describes exactly what you did to fix the issue, and include all of the code changes you made in order to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap realImage;
         final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
          options.inSampleSize = 5;

            options.inPurgeable=true;                   

            options.inInputShareable=true;             


        realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length,options);
        ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(path + c.getTime().getSeconds()
                    + ".jpg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Log.d("EXIF value",
                    exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
            if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
            } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("8")) {
                realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
            } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
            } else if (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                realImage = rotate(realImage, 90);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        image.setImageBitmap(realImage);
```

Comment: hi devcelebi , is "data" was returned data in onActivityResult and what is "ExifInterface"  and "c" ? Thanks for quick reply .

Comment: Exifinterface for orientation.c is name of the file.if you dont need orientation control,you wont write exif.You can try to use bitmapfactory.options in this code